# For loop limit problem when query by tags (Shopify Liquid)

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm new in **Shopify** theme development. I'm stuck in `for` `loop` query. `for` `loop` not working properly when try to query by `tag`. Below is my code.

```
{% assign query_tag = block.settings.home_section_tag %}
{% if collections.new-releases.products.size > 0 %}
    {% for product in collections.new-releases.products limit:4 %}
        {% if product.tags contains query_tag %}
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <h3>{{ product.title | escape  }}</h3>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Above code show me only 1 product it supposed to be 4 products. Also `limit:1`, `limit:2`, `limit:3` not working (No product showing), `limit:4` show me 1 product, `limit:5` show me 2 products, `limit:6` show me 3 products, `limit:7` show me 3 product, `limit:8` show me 4 products (it's on going). if I remove product query by `tag` `limit:` working properly. I don't understand what is the issue with my code.

I need help for this issue and need an explanation why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly. Initially, you get **first** 4 products from the `new-releases` collection. And then you filter the result by the `query_tag` within the loop.

You can:

- Increase the limit to 50 (not good if your collection has more items), or
- Create another collection filtered by the `query_tag` and use `for` loop on that collection limiting to 4

Comment: Is there any way to query by `tags` then `limit` the product?

Comment: No, only by creating a collection with a tag condition or by going to the collection URL e.g. `/collections/new-releases/your-tag` but doesn't seem that it will suit you.